# Non zero solution of matrix equation of order $2$

Tags: matrices

> A non zero solution to the following matrix equation is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6\\ 
8 & -6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y\end{bmatrix}=6\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$

What I try:

$$\tag{1} 2x+6y=6x\Longrightarrow 4x=6y$$

$$ \tag{2} 8x-6y=6y\Longrightarrow 8x=12y$$

So these two equation are same and we get infinite number of solutions.

For non zero solutions , Let $x=k$. Then $\displaystyle y=\frac{2}{3}k$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\neq 0$

So we have $$(x,y)=(k,\frac{2}{3}k)$$

Is i am right. Then  How can i get non zero solution.

Please help me . Thanks

Comment: You say you have an infinite number of solution. Can you give us explicitely just one of the solutions ?

Comment: Then can we say that if $x=k\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Then $\displaystyle y=\frac{2}{3}k$. So we have $\displaystyle (x,y)=\bigg(k,\frac{2}{3}k\bigg)$

Comment: Choose a value $\neq 0 $ for $x$ and calculate the corrisponding value for $y$

Comment: I'm not getting the ' Then How can i get non zero solution'...you have already established them

Comment: What "non-zero solution" means is that $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, i.e. either $x\ne 0$ or $y\ne 0$. By choosing $k\ne 0$ you get both $x$ and $y$ nonzero.